# Can I show icons in System Monitor on Ubntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, system-monitor

Without icon is usable, but having icons makes it easier to be distinguished.
I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The System Monitor that is pre-installed on Ubuntu 18.04 is installed via the [snap package](https://docs.snapcraft.io/snaps/intro), not from the traditional apt repo. You can verify that by running `snap list`, the output should contain `gnome-system-monitor`.

The snap execution environment doesn't see any of the icons on your system (local or system-wide). So this is somewhat an expected behaviour.

As a workaround you may remove the snap applications by running

```
snap remove gnome-system-monitor
```

and install the traditional one by running

```
sudo apt install gnome-system-monitor
```

Comment: Actually, I installed it from Ubuntu Software. Didn't know there is a difference, can I say it is better to use traditional apt repo than Ubuntu Software?